# Apply CSS normalize / reset to single element and children

Tags: css, normalize, normalize-css

I have a plugin that needs to work with multiple themes without inheriting the styles from that theme.

I know I can reset all elements using this

```
 #element, #element * { -- reset css here --}
```

But then I loose all styling. I actually would prefer to use normalize (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssnormalize/) which has a contextual css file.

But how do I apply this to a single div and all children.

Another illustrative example.

I have

```
    <div id="test-element">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

I want the table not to inherit any styling -  to be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the css file, I would say the easiest way would be using a compiled css approach (i.e.: less).

You could do something like this using less:

```
prefixedCssNormalize.less

#test-element {
   /* paste contents of the css normalize here. */
}
```

Paste (or import using a templating lib) the css file into the place where the comments are.

When you compile the less file into css, all rules in the cssnormalize will be prefixed with `#test-element`. Thus making the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the to be updated styles are loaded or added after other files/styles are loaded.
the style applies at the end has more weightage than previous.

neutralize the inherited style for particular element as

```
#test-element , #test-element * {
/* your normalize code */
}
```

and then add your new/updated style.

But keep in mind, if !important is used or inherited parent chile links, it would be a tedious task to normalize and apply the new style.